# In which case Firestore adds oldEmail to collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm updating a user's email with the following code:

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
  user.email,
  password,
);
user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(() => updateEmail(user, newEmail))
```

It updates the email ok but I thought that it would add the 'oldEmail' field to the user's collection so that I could use it later but it doesn't; what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Auth SDK won't keep any record for you in Firestore. If you want to keep old email in Firestore then you would have to explicitly add it in Firestore.

```js
user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(async () => {
  // update old email in DB
  await db.collection("users").doc(user.id).update({oldEmail: "oldname@domain.tld"})

  // update email
  await updateEmail(user, newEmail)
})
```

Comment: It's just that while writing this code I tried many different variations and one of them definitely saved the oldEmail field to the collection...but I completely lost it and  maybe this was a result of some improper update, I'm not sure

Comment: @MikeL. Can you elaborate the issue with some code and error is any?